# how to remove previous routes in HERE JS API?

Tags: javascript, here-api

I want to remove route from previous calculation in HERE Maps, in my code bellow, if i do two times calculation, the new routes overlay the previous routes.
................................................................................................................................................................

```
function addRouteShapeToMap(route)
{
 // map.removeObject(route.shape);
 var strip = new H.geo.Strip(),
 routeShape = route.shape,
 polyline;

 routeShape.forEach(function(point)
 {
  var parts = point.split(',');
  strip.pushLatLngAlt(parts[0], parts[1]);
  });

 polyline = new H.map.Polyline(strip,
 {
  style:
  {
    lineWidth: 4,
    strokeColor: 'rgba(0, 128, 255, 0.7)'
   }
  });
 // Add the polyline to the map
 map.addObject(polyline);
 // And zoom to its bounding rectangle
  map.setViewBounds(polyline.getBounds(), true);
}
```

and this is code for add maneuvers symbol :

```
function addManueversToMap(route)
{
  var svgMarkup = '<svg width="18" height="18" ' +
                  'xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' +
                  '<circle cx="8" cy="8" r="8" ' +
                  'fill="#1b468d" stroke="white" stroke-width="1"  />' +
                  '</svg>',
  dotIcon = new H.map.Icon(svgMarkup,
   {
     anchor: 

    { 
       x: 8, 
       y: 8 
    }
    }),
  group = new H.map.Group(), i, j;

 // Add a marker for each maneuver
 for (i = 0; i < route.leg.length; i += 1)
 {
   for (j = 0; j < route.leg[i].maneuver.length; j += 1)
{
  // Get the next maneuver.
  maneuver = route.leg[i].maneuver[j];
  // Add a marker to the maneuvers group
  var marker = new H.map.Marker({
    lat: maneuver.position.latitude,
    lng: maneuver.position.longitude
  },
  {
    icon: dotIcon
  });
  marker.instruction = maneuver.instruction;
  group.addObject(marker);
  }
}

 group.addEventListener('tap', function(evt)
{
  map.setCenter(evt.target.getPosition());
  openBubble(
   evt.target.getPosition(), evt.target.instruction);
}, false);

  // Add the maneuvers group to the map
  map.addObject(group);
}
```

than if the route success, where can i place code `map.removeObject(route);` in this function?

```
function onSuccess(result)
    {
      var route = result.response.route[0];
      addRouteShapeToMap(route);
      addManueversToMap(route);
      addWaypointsToPanel(route.waypoint);
      addManueversToPanel(route);
      addSummaryToPanel(route.summary);
    }
```

help me to solve my code..

Answer (score 3):

This might not be the best solution, but it works for me.
Make sure to provide the same `id` name both for polyline and group. 
Before you `map.addObject(polyline)`, give a name for id:

```
polyline.id = "route";
// Add the polyline to the map
map.addObject(polyline);
```

Also the same do for `map.addObject(group)`:

```
 group.id = "route";
 // Add the maneuvers group to the map
 map.addObject(group);
```

Finally create a new function as follows:

```
function removeObjectById(id){
   for (object of map.getObjects()){
    if (object.id===id){
        map.removeObject(object);
        }
    }
}
```

When you execute the function by providing id, e.g in your console browser, it will remove both polyline and maneuvers:

```
removeObjectById("route");
```

Comment: Thanks! I was searching for a method to clearing the map, from long time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using [this example](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/servicesRouting/map-with-route-from-a-to-b) as the basis for your code.

`map.removeObject(route)` won't work, because `route` is not an object on the map. The objects you want to remove are the `group` and `polyline` objects. To do so you probably want to change the scope of those variables by declaring them outside of the `addRouteShapeToMap` and `addManueversToMap` functions. If you declare them at the top of your code:

```
polyline = new H.map.Polyline(strip, {
  style: {
    lineWidth: 4,
    strokeColor: 'rgba(0, 128, 255, 0.7)'
  }
});
var group = new  H.map.Group();
```

you can then use

```
map.removeObject(polyline);
map.removeObject(group);
```

to remove the line and markers from the map later on (for example when start another route calculation). Note that `onSuccess` is not the right place to add this, as the objects would be removed right after adding them, thus preventing them from ever being visible.

Comment: it still not remove the line and marker.. where should i place them..  `map.removeobject()`

Comment: i also send an email to developersupport with the complete script code attached.. Ticket [18190]  - how to remove previous route  ..please check the ticket.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that before **map.removeObject(polyline);** polyline is set as an object when map.addObject is used.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the route to the map instance, add it to a group. 

So here should be the steps that you should follow:
1. Create a group, and have a reference to it. 
2. When you add a route, add it to the group (like this)

```
this.group.addObject(new this.H.map.Polyline(
      lineString, { style: { lineWidth: 4 } }
));
```

3. When you want to clear the map, you can clear the group (like this)

   this.group.removeAll();

I have tested this logic. it is working fine!